# I am getting this error using django taggit "Can't call add with a non-instance manager"

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I'm trying to add a few tags to my post object when I save them, using django taggit. So I tried this

```
    def panties():
        from lxml import html
        pan_url = 'http://www.ideos.org'
        shtml = requests.get(pan_url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(shtml.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'video'})
        name = 'pan videos'
        author = User.objects.get(id=1)
        tags = Post.tags.add("Musica", "video")   <------here

        def youtube_link(url):
            youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
            video_row = soupdata.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})
            entries = [{'text': str(div),
                        } for div in video_row]

            tubby = str(entries[4])
            urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', tubby)
            return urls

        def embed(url):
            new_embed = url.replace("watch?v=", "embed/")
            return new_embed

        entries = [{'href': div.a.get('href'),
                    'src': youtube_link(div.a.get('href'))[1],
                    'text': div.h4.text,
                    'comments': div.h4.text,
                    'name': name,
                    'url': div.a.get('href'),
                    'embed': embed(youtube_link(div.a.get('href'))[0]),
                    'author': author,
                    'video': True,
                    'tag': tags <------here
                    } for div in video_row][:13]
```

but that gave me the error message

```
Can't call add with a non-instance manager
```

So I then tried this

```
    def panties():
        from lxml import html
        pan_url = 'http://www.ideos.org'
        shtml = requests.get(pan_url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(shtml.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'video'})
        name = 'pan videos'
        author = User.objects.get(id=1)
        post = Post() <------created instance
        tags = post.tags.add("Musica", "video")

        def youtube_link(url):
            youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
            video_row = soupdata.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})
            entries = [{'text': str(div),
                        } for div in video_row]

            tubby = str(entries[4])
            urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', tubby)
            return urls

        def embed(url):
            new_embed = url.replace("watch?v=", "embed/")
            return new_embed

        entries = [{'href': div.a.get('href'),
                    'src': youtube_link(div.a.get('href'))[1],
                    'text': div.h4.text,
                    'comments': div.h4.text,
                    'name': name,
                    'url': div.a.get('href'),
                    'embed': embed(youtube_link(div.a.get('href'))[0]),
                    'author': author,
                    'video': True,
                    'tag': tags
                    } for div in video_row][:13]
```

and it gave me this error message

Post objects need to have a primary key value before you can access their tags. How Can I make this work? is what I'm doing even possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add tags to the Post manager.
You want to add tags to a Post instance.

You need a saved Post instance before you can add the tags

e.g.

`post_instance = Post.objects.get_or_create(foo=bar)
tags = post_instance.tags.add("Musica", "video")`

Comment: thanks for the response. I understand that, but how do I make it work in my situation?

Comment: ```post = Post(some_field=some_data); post.save(); tags = post.tags.add("Musica", "video")```

Answer (score 0):

With the aide of @luke_aus answer I figured it out. this is just what my code looks like now for others who may want to see how to actually do it. It went from this.

```
    for entry in entries:
            post = Post()
            post.title = entry['text']
            title = post.title
            if not Post.objects.filter(title=title):
                post.title = entry['text']
                post.name = entry['name']
                post.url = entry['url']
                post.body = entry['comments']
                post.image_url = entry['src']
                post.video_path = entry['embed']
                post.author = entry['author']
                post.video = entry['video']
                post.status = 'draft'
                post.save()
```

to this

```
    for entry in entries:
            post = Post()
            post.title = entry['text']
            title = post.title
            if not Post.objects.filter(title=title):
                post.title = entry['text']
                post.name = entry['name']
                post.url = entry['url']
                post.body = entry['comments']
                post.image_url = entry['src']
                post.video_path = entry['embed']
                post.author = entry['author']
                post.video = entry['video']
                post.status = 'draft'
                post.save()

                saved_post = Post.objects.get(title=title)
                tags = saved_post.tags.add("Musica", "video")
                post.tags = tags
                post.save()
```

hope this helps someone

Comment: Glad you got it. You should probably shorten this code for SO purposes...the exact fields don't really matter :)

Comment: @luke_aus hey what's SO. I'm really pretty green when it comes to python. I learned python via Django.

Comment: @loose So did I! - SO = Stack Overflow. Best to give shortened examples that illustrate the main points you are trying to make

Comment: Also in your code in this answer, you already have the post object. Your line                 saved_post = Post.objects.get(title=title) is just getting the object you just saved. So ```saved_post = post``` You don't need the additional query. Also you can replace the last 4 lines with just this one: ```post.tags.add("Musica", "video")``` - you don't need to resave post after adding entires to a m2m model in django - so that last post.ave() call does nothing.

Comment: @luke_aus modified it,  tried it, it works. I am greatful